# Agrupar por igualdade

Tags: mysql, group-by

Eu preciso agrupar o resultado quando houver registros iguais, independente da ordem, sempre que as mesmas cores forem escolhidas - agrupar as cores e os usuários. Preciso produzir um output como o abaixo:

```
0 => array( 'cores' => 'azul, verde' , 'user' => '1, 3' )
1 => array( 'cores' => 'azul'        , 'user' => '2' )

// Usuarios 1 e 3 escolheram azul e verde
// Usuario 2 escolheu azul
```

Minha tabela

```
TABELA.ESCOLHA    TABELA.CORES
ID | USER         ID | ESCOLHA | CORES
---------         ---------------------
 1 | 1             1 | 1       | azul
 2 | 2             2 | 1       | verde
 3 | 3             3 | 2       | azul
                   4 | 3       | azul
                   5 | 3       | verde
```

Minha query

```
select
    group_concat( user  ) user
  , group_concat( cores ) cores
from escolha
inner join cores
        on cores.escolha = escolha.id
  group by user
```

Tentei `group by user`, tentei com outros campos, mas não funcionaram como o esperado.

Comment: A sua query não produziu o resultado que você queria? 
Veja: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/587a3/1

Comment: @vmartins, não produziu, pois eu queria agrupar `user 1` com `user 3` por serem iguais, e o resultado seria um array com 2 valores: `1 => 'user 1, user 3' , 2 => 'user 2'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  group_concat(user) user,
  cores
FROM (
  SELECT
      user,
      group_concat(cores ORDER BY cores ASC) cores
  FROM
      escolha
  INNER JOIN cores ON cores.escolha = escolha.id
  GROUP BY
      user
) tmp
GROUP BY cores
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/519ed/8/0

Comment: É quase isso. Eu inclui para *user 2* as cores *amarelo, azul*, e ele agrupou apenas pelo user, e no caso deveriam ser 2 linhas( user 2: amarelo e user 2: azul). Creio que mudando o `GROUP BY` resolva.